# std::swap does not call my custom swap implementation c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, swap

I have code like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct thing {
    void swap(thing & other){
        std::cout << "swap method" << std::endl;
    }
};

void swap(thing & a, thing & b) {
    std::cout << "swap function" << std::endl;

    a.swap(b);
}

struct another{
    thing a;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    another a, b;

    std::swap(a, b);
}
```

If executed, it prints nothing - e.g. it does not use my "custom" `swap`.

I read I should NOT std::swap specialization.

Do I need to do custom swap for class `another`, or I am missing something?

Comment: How do you expect your custom `swap()` to be called? You are yourself invoking `std::swap()` after all!

Comment: well this is what exactly I did not understood correctly.  
so I need template specialization in std namespace after all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::swap` won't call your `swap` implementation. What you're supposed to do (in generic code) is to let overload resolution pick your own:

```
namespace stuff
{
  struct foo { void swap(foo& other); };

  swap(foo& lhs, foo& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }
}

int main()
{
  foo a, b;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 42;

  using std::swap;

  swap(i, j); // calls std::swap
  swap(a, b); // calls stuff::swap(stuff::foo&, stuff::foo&) via ADL
}
```

Comment: so `swap` is more for duck typing? and I need to add either template specialization or to do one more swap function for the `another` class?

Comment: @Nick You could specialize the `std::swap` template for your type, but the common practice is to define your types and functions on your own namespace and then use the trick shown above (`using std::swap` in the scope you want to do the swapping in.)

Comment: @Nick: "duck typing" implies parametric polymorphism (templates, macros), whereas having to create versions of `swap` for each type is squarely ad-hoc polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap` expects `thing`'s. Is this what you want?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    another a, b;

    using std::swap; // let the compiler decide which swap to use

    swap(a.a, b.a); // calls swap(thing & a, thing & b) and thing.swap
}
```

Comment: Where does the `.a` come from?

Comment: @nwp `.a` is of type `thing`

Answer (score 0):

You call explicitly for `std::swap` - there is no reason your custom method should be called.

However in case you change this - be sure to change the interface of the method - in this form compilation errors will occur.